# Tomtom webfleet message api returning message status flags with message text

Tags: python, json, tomtom

I am retrieving device messages from TomTom telematics weblfeet api, using **showMessages** action.
I am getting json response as follows.

```
{
    "msgid": 102001623621,
    "msg_time": "22/08/2018 12:24:08",
    "msg_flag": "R",
    "msg_category": 1,
    "msg_text": "Message \"Hello Tomtoim!!!\" read",
    "msg_refid": 101930037863,
    "msg_reftype": 2,
    "objectno": "TEST",
    "pos_time": "22/08/2018 12:24:04",
    "pos_text": "",
    "objectuid": "1-44061-6662F76F14"
}
```

Can anyone tell me why instead of just Message as **"Hello Tomtoim!!!** i am getting **"Message \"Hello Tomtoim!!!\" read"** ?
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Because the quotation marks have to be escaped.
You can read about JSON format at [rfc4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627)